# How do I include many columns in pd.melt function instead of just typing each and everyone out?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, jupyter-lab, pandas-melt

I have a data set that has the following columns. funciton: pd.melt()
years name date m1 m2 m3 m4 m5 m6 …. to m12

I set me variable name to month and try to include m1-m12, but I just cant get it to work. it will instead put everything in the new week column which looks like
week
year
name
date
m1
m2
I don't want the week year name date, is there a way to just put m1-m12 in like indexing? i have tried it it didn't work

Comment: it doesnt come out as how i wanted it...

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your input and expected output?

Comment: As Jon mentioned, a sample dataframe with expected output dataframe will be helpful

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

sample output
month
m1
m2
m3
...
m12
here is the answer i come up with using iloc!
sorry for asking a easy question that I can figure out myself
pd.melt(.......value_vars=billboard.iloc[-12:])

Comment: Kindly mark it as accepted or delete the question, so it is no longer an active question

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: hi! how do i do that?